# Application stops responding when using Process.waitFor()

Tags: java, processbuilder, linphone

I'm launching an external application from within my Java application (8u11). However the application becomes non-responsive to UI input up under Windows XP and Windows 7 with the standard hour glass/spinner.

I've narrowed this problem down to whether or not I use Process.waitFor(). If I call it I see the problems, if I don't it works fine. Also the application un-freezes if I then quit the Java application.

My question is why is this the case - how can calling waitFor() possibly effect the internal runnings of a child process? And how can I avoid this problem?

The application in question is LinPhone.exe but I don't believe the issue is specific to the application - there must be some general way in which it handles standard IO etc which the way I'm interfering with by calling waitFor().

I need to use Process.waitFor() so I can track when the application has exited.

I've simplified the issue to this SCCEE.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LinphoneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        String phoneAppPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Linphone\\bin\\linphone.exe";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(phoneAppPath);
        // move up from bin/linephone.exe
        File workingDir = new File(phoneAppPath).getParentFile()
                .getParentFile();
        processBuilder.directory(workingDir);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        try {
            while (((line = stdout.readLine()) != null)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, "process wait").start();

        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You're saying the process you're waiting for is unresponsive?

Comment: Please have a look at [When RunTime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html). And do your waiting in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks. I do the waiting on a Background thread as it is ultimately trigger from the UI thread, I removed that detail from the SSCCE. I'll add it again and see if I can still reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you doing what the article I linked to recommends with regard to the process's streams? If you don't handle them and run out of buffer memory, you could bork your program.

Comment: Problem 1: Your posted code puts the application to sleep for a very very long time. Problem 2: Can you post an SSCCE that we all can all run and test? Most of us don't have linphone.exe. 3. You still haven't mentioned how you're handling the process's streams.

Comment: I've updated my example to be more representative of how I'm handling streams. I spotted my mistake too. redirectErrorStream() should be redirectErrorStream(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise discussion, I was not handling standard error streams causing linphone to lockup as its output buffer for standard error became full especially as linphone produces a lot of verbose output on standard error. [When RunTime.exec wont](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) provides excellent summary of the pitfalls involved in calling processes from Java.

There was also a typo, I was calling the non-standard named getter

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
```

when I should have been calling the "setter"

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```